# Update operation in xunit using moq

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, moq, xunit.net

I am trying to update using xunit and moq repository but my code doesn't update the changes. I am not sure if the update code that I have written is correct or not. Could you please help me with the same?

```
[Fact]
private async void SetPortfolioCompanyStatusAsync()
{
    int _id = 1;
    var mockUserRepository = new Mock<IPortfolioCompanyManagement>();
    var mockUserRepository1 = new Mock<IUserManagement>();

    mockUserRepository.Setup(c => c.GetPortfolioCompanies( It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(moqData.portfolioCompanies));
    mockUserRepository.Setup(m => m.UpdatePortfolioCompany(moqData.portfolioCompanies[0], It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(moqData.portfolioCompanies[0]);

    PortfolioCompany product = new PortfolioCompany()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Test Private Company 1",//change data
        DealCode = "PRIV1",
        IsActive = false,
        IsPrivate = true
    };

    var controller = new UsersController(mockUserRepository1.Object, mockUserRepository.Object);
    var result1 = await controller.SetPortfolioCompanyStatus(product, It.IsAny<CancellationToken>());//this always returns null. Expected to return the updated value.

    var result =  controller.GetAllPortfolioCompanies( It.IsAny<CancellationToken>());
    var z = result.Result.Value.Count();
}
```

my mock data is like :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using ValuationsReporting.Models;

namespace ValuationsReporting.Tests
{
    public partial class MoqData
    {
        public List<PortfolioCompany> portfolioCompanies = new List<PortfolioCompany> {
                 new PortfolioCompany
                 {
                     Id=1,
                    Name = "Test Private Company 1",
                    DealCode = "PRIV1",
                    IsActive = true,
                    IsPrivate = true
                 },
                 new PortfolioCompany
                 {
                    Id=2,
                    Name = "Test Public Company 1",
                    DealCode = "PUBL1",
                    IsActive = true,
                    IsPrivate = false
                 },
                new PortfolioCompany
                 {
                     Id=3,
                    Name = "Test Private Company 2",
                    DealCode = "PRIV2",
                    IsActive = true,
                    IsPrivate = true
                 },
                 new PortfolioCompany
                 {
                    Id=4,
                    Name = "Test Public Company 2",
                    DealCode = "PUBL2",
                    IsActive = true,
                    IsPrivate = false
                 },
                new PortfolioCompany
                 {
                     Id=5,
                    Name = "Test Private Company 3",
                    DealCode = "PRIV3",
                    IsActive = false,
                    IsPrivate = true
                 },
                 new PortfolioCompany
                 {
                    Id=6,
                    Name = "Test Public Company 3",
                    DealCode = "PUBL3",
                    IsActive = false,
                    IsPrivate = false
                 }
            };
    }
}
```

My controller code is like :

```
public async Task<ActionResult<PortfolioCompany>> SetPortfolioCompanyStatus([FromBody] PortfolioCompany portfolioCompany, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    if (portfolioCompany == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(portfolioCompany));

    if (portfolioCompany.Id <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(portfolioCompany.Id));
    var z = await _portfolioCompanyManagement.UpdatePortfolioCompany(portfolioCompany, cancellationToken);
    return await _portfolioCompanyManagement.UpdatePortfolioCompany(portfolioCompany, cancellationToken);
}
```

I am trying to update the values but it always returns null. but when I try to get the data I get all the data perfectly fine but the update doesn't happen.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any clarification

Comment: The problem is with the setup of the `UpdatePortfolioCompany`. Moq use equals method to check the identity, you setup method with one instance and then invoke it with other, these 2 instances are not equal I suppose... I mean `moqData.portfolioCompanies[0]` and `product`(I do expect that `PortfolioCompany` doesn't override Equals method or implement IEquatable...)

Comment: @johnny thanks for the response. So how do you think I can solve this issue? See product is a list that I created here just to update the value. Moqdata.portfoliocompanies[0] is also a list where I have 6 records as you can see on the top. Could you help me to solve this issue?

Comment: There are plenty ways to solve it, the point is to understand it. For example try using `moqData.portfolioCompanies[0]` instead of `product`.

Comment: @johnny then how  will I send the data that has to be updated . So basically in this example I am updating isactive which is true to false

Comment: Then you need to return the same instance you have passed to the function... something like:`mockUserRepository.Setup(m => m.UpdatePortfolioCompany(It.IsAny<PortfolioCompany>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns((PortfolioCompany p, CancellationToken c) => Task.FromResult(p));`